# Comparing chararrays in linked list in the C programming language

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

How do you compare and sort chararrays in a linked list, cant you compare like this 'Smith' > 'Andersson' ?

```
struct person {
char name[20];
struct person *nextPerson;
};

.
void createNode(PersonPtr *sPtr, struct person t[]){
  PersonPtr newPtr; /* pointer to new node */
  PersonPtr previousPtr; /* pointer to previus node in  list */
  PersonPtr currentPtr; /* pointer to current node in list */
.
/* loop to find correct location in the list */
while (currentPtr != NULL && t->name > currentPtr->name) { /* this will not sort on name */
  previousPtr = currentPtr; /* walk to... */
  currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPerson; /* ...next node */
}/* end while */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, but not quite, you can't just use ">" or "<" on strings.  What you want is [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/).

What you want is:

```
while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(t->name,currentPtr->name) > 0)
```

Comment: Ok, great, had in my mind in C it "automatically" compared a chararray since char = int.

Comment: yet it can't automatically compare an int array, so it makes sense actually.

Comment: char is an integer but it is not an 'int'.

Answer (score 1):

man [strcmp](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strcmp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+4.0&arch=i386&format=html)(3)

**Edit**: Your variable `t->name` is a pointer to a char. When you do `t->name > currentPtr->name` you're comparing their values, i.e the chars addresses.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just use the **>** operator. You need to call the library function **strcmp**.

Answer (score 0):

[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If by "chararrays" yo mean "strings", you can compare them by using [strcmp](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strcmp.html).